# create list of data time from an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, datetime

I have a weird format of date time information which is saved as a separate string. Such as,

```
print(time)
print(time[0])
print(type(time[0]))
print(type(time[0][0]))

[['2' '0' '2' ... '3' '2' '3']
 ['2' '0' '2' ... '4' '2' '3']
 ['2' '0' '2' ... '5' '2' '4']
 ...
 ['2' '0' '2' ... '5' '2' '7']
 ['2' '0' '2' ... '6' '2' '6']
 ['2' '0' '2' ... '7' '2' '0']]
['2' '0' '2' '2' '0' '5' '2' '1' '0' '7' '1' '3' '2' '3']
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

The goal is to convert each row of the array into a proper DateTime format.
The outcome can be both list or an array.
For example,

```
['2' '0' '2' '2' '0' '5' '2' '1' '0' '7' '1' '3' '2' '3']
```

into
DateTime format 20220521-07:13:23

As the original data has multiple rows, I need to loop through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your list is:

```
l = ['2','0','2','2','0','5','2','1','0','7','1','3','2','3']
```

you can use:

```
time = [l[8+2*i]+l[9+2*i] for i in range(3)]
date = ''.join(l[:8]) + '- '  + ':'.join(time)
print(date)

>>> 20220521- 07:13:23
```